# Coprime multiplicative orders modulo infinitely many primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Is it true that there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that the multiplicative orders of $2$ and $3$ are coprime $\pmod{p}$? By this I mean their order in $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^*$. 
If the answer is positive, can this be extended to $p_1,\dots,p_k$ instead of $2,3$, asking that the orders are pairwise coprime?

Comment: I think this may be a hard question, maybe even an open question. If you get no answers by the end of the 7 days, you might try posting it to MathOverflow.

Comment: Related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%27s_conjecture_on_primitive_roots

Comment: Up to the $200,000$th prime I have only found two instances where the orders are coprime (the $124$th and $49,059$th primes)...that isn't very strong evidence for the conjecture.